# Writing an equation between graph elements

Tags: bayesian

Can we write an equation for

**P(R|S) = ?**

[image]

If you refer to a document it will be great.

Comment: What is `R`? What is `S`? Where does the graph come in?

Comment: I know P(W), P(R), P(S), P(C) etc. I want to formulate P(R|S) without using sth. like P(S|R), P(~R|S), P(~S|R) etc.? You can see that related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234324/finding-probability-of-psw-at-bayesian-network-of-rain-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the question you link to on StackExchange, I assume that we know the probabilities $P(C)$, $P(S|C)$, $P(R|C)$, $P(W|S,R)$, and the same quantities with events replaced by their negations.  (Where $C$ is the event that it's cloudy, etc.)

The graph tells us that the joint distribution can be calculated by multiplying  together the distributions of each node conditional on its parents, so in your case, $P(C,S,R,W) = P(C) \cdot P(S | C) \cdot P(R | C) \cdot P(W | R,S)$.

You can work out any probability you want from this using the elementary rules of probability.  For example,

$P(C,S,W) = P(C,S,R,W) + P(C,S,\neg R,W)$.

$P(C, S | W) = \frac{P(C,S,W)}{P(W)}$.

For the specific problem you give ($P(R|S)$) you can ignore $W$ completely, so
$P(C,S,R) = P(C) \cdot P(S | C) \cdot P(R | C)$, and then sum over $C$ to get $P(R,S)$ and use the formula for conditional probability.